# How do I fix this while loop more efficiently?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, stack

This loop is working properly

```
y = pop(stk2, &top2);
while(y != -1) {
   /* ... and at the end */
   y = pop(stk2, &top2);
}
```

but I don't like repeating the `pop` call. I have tried this

```
while(y = pop(stk2, &top2) != -1)
```

and this

```
while((y = pop(stk2, &top2)) != -1)
```

But neither of them works.

Comment: Are you quite sure that `while(y = pop(stk2, &top2) != -1)` shouldn't be `while((y = pop(stk2, &top2)) != -1)`? What you wrote will be evaluated as `while(y = (pop(stk2, &top2) != -1))`, so `y` is effectively boolean. You said "it doesn't work as well" but it *isn't the same*.

Comment: What about `do { y = ...; } while(y != -1);`?

Comment: Please format code appropriately as such – entire lines/blocks of codes you can by indenting by four spaces or by surrounding with a pair of triple backticks (`\`\`\`code\`\`\``; each triple backtick on its separate line), inline code you surround with a pair of single backticks (`\`code\``).

Comment: Please show the complete code block that does not work copy/pasted, instead of fragments which describe what you allegedly did. You only show almost-complete code that *does* work.

Comment: What does it means "but neither of them works"??? The second should...

Comment: Why would you even begin to think cramming everything into one line is in any way better?  It's harder to read, harder to maintain, and extremely bug-prone.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the original post said the second of the two attempts "did not work *as well*" which I eventually assumed to be an English language issue, and made that edit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Re “Why would you even begin to think cramming everything into one line is in any way better?”: It conforms to a recognized principle of good design: DRY (Don’t Repeat Yourself). There are two principles in tension here: DRY versus easier to read. In the absence of good studies of which is better in this case, we only have opinion. I hardly find `while ((y = pop(stk2, &top2)) != -1)` harder to read. Certainly I have found it at times more effort to find some correlated line in code than to read a single line like this…

Comment: … As for harder to main, that is dubious, as having one single line that is not terribly long or complicated and whose only violation is that some people do not like its form is arguably easier to maintain than two widely separated simpler lines. The latter is prone to errors in which one line is updated and the other is not. And there is doubt that it is bug-prone, let alone extremely bug prone.

Comment: Style questions are eminently imponderable and endlessly debatable, but @EricPostpischil has it exactly right: DRY and crystal-clear readability are absolutely in tension here.  I used to hate the way C programmers habitually tried to "cram everything into one line", and it can certainly be abused, but the "fetch and process inputs as long as there aren't any more" idiom is classic, virtuous, and must be learned and recognized by any C programmer whether they like it or not.

Comment: See also the discussion of the "cryptic brevity which C is notorious for" in [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6b.html).

Comment: @JustaNobody Yes, there is a better way of writing this, and you have already hit on it: `while((y = pop(stk2, &top2)) != -1)`.  We need to figure out why this didn't work for you, because it should have, and it's a good way of writing this loop, without repeating the `pop()` call.

Comment: @SteveSummit apparantly there was some issue with compiler. I tried the same code again and it is working. Some glitch might have happened.

Comment: @JustaNobody LOL.  Those darn glitchy compilers.  Glad you got it working.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *And there is doubt that it is bug-prone, let alone extremely bug prone.*  You've been active here how many years?  How is it that you miss the continual flow of questions caused by bugs from not accounting for the proper precedence of the `=` assignment operator when used in `if` or `while` statements?  If it's not bug-prone, why does MISRA ban it as a bug-prone construct?  Cramming the assignment into `if` or `while` statements is a dated idiom from the days it was idiomatic to put lead in gasoline.  Might as well cite COBOL for good examples of programming style.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I am kind of new here. I apologize for the improper formatting. I will work on it future requests.

Comment: @AndrewHenle In all seriousness, I don't remember ever seeing a question here involving proper precedence of the `=` operator in `if` or `while` statements.  (Not saying there haven't ever been any, but I wouldn't think they're at all frequent.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Re “How is it that you miss…”: That is *ad hominem* and inappropriate. Re “bugs from not accounting for the proper precedence”: As I noted, there are **two** rules in tension. Arguing there are bugs from one issue is not an argument that they exceed bugs from the other issue; it does not give us information about which choice is better. Additionally, the precedence issue can be mitigated by putting `-1` as the left operand of `!=`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Re “why does MISRA ban it”: The MISRA Consortium makes rules for MISRA’s purposes. Those may be based on the personal opinions of the participants, but, even if they are not, they are for MISRA’s goals, which may prioritize software “safety” over other goals. Software engineers serving other purposes may prioritize performance or low cost of development or other goals. E.g., a high cost of development might prevent a game from getting to market timely and becoming profitable, whereas a rare execution error might not. Re “good examples”: Your opinion of what is good is not a fact.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question it looks like you want to execute the code statement of `y = pop(stk2, &top2);` before breaking the while loop. This can be done using `do-while` loop.

The the `do-while` helps you to execute the code statement at least once before checking the condition. The loop exits if the condition is met.

Your code can be organized in a following way:

```
do{
    /* ... and at the end */
    y = pop(stk2, &top2);
}while(y != -1)
```

Comment: but the loop body does not have a value for `y` to work with on the first iteration

Comment: Do- while doesn't work since, in the first iteration y should be checked for underflow. In do-while the first iteration assumes y!=-1 to execute code belong. So that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @JustaNobody Then the code in your question itself is wrong as well, you have exactly the same what a do-while would do: `y = pop(stk2, &top2); /* you first assign by popping, too!!! */ while(y != -1) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't like" is not a rationale for anything. First of all, you have to verify that having an extra function call before the loop is actually causing some performance issue or if you are just imagining that. I wrote some artificial example of your code and disassembled, ending up with something like (x86):

```
    call    pop
    cmp     eax, -1
    je      .L2
.L3:
    ...
    call    pop
    cmp     eax, -1
    jne     .L3
```

Apart from the function call itself, the `cmp` might also stall execution somewhat since it is a branch. However, the total amount of calls/branches will not be different just because you rewrite the code.

Then I wrote something like

```c
int y = 0;
  
while(y != -1) {
  printf("do something with y here %d", y);
  y = pop(stk2, &top2);
}
```

And I noticed that the compiler removes the first `y != 1` comparison since it can deduce that `y` is definitely not `-1` the first time in the loop. Essentially the compiler made a `do-while` loop on the assembler level. We only saved one single branch though, so this is a micro-optimization very likely not worth our time to worry about. So your code was probably ok to begin with.

More importantly, the code above is slightly more readable with just one function call. However `while((y = pop(stk2, &top2)) != -1)` is much less readable, relies on the bad practice of assignment in conditions and it is very dubious if this have any impact on performance at all.

Best practices:

- Only manually optimize code when you have found an actual bottleneck and when you have a decent understanding of the underlying hardware. (Obviously it's of course always ok to optimize code that is unnecessary slow on an algorithm level.)
- "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY) is often a good principle, as long as it isn't taken to the extreme (in which case it is harmful). When calling the same function with the same parameters, it is a good idea to only do that function call at one place in the code, for readability and maintainability purposes.
- Avoid assignment inside `if`/loop conditions. It's a well-known safety hazard and it makes code less readable. In general, avoid code which does multiple things on a single line, including code trying to use as many operators as possible on a single line (The operator precedence bug `y = pop(stk2, &top2) != -1` is an illustration why). Avoid multiple side effects inside a single expression.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I personally do not know much about assembly language. So this was pretty insightful. I can see your point on memory management.
Here I was trying to reduce line of code. My working solution was pretty unintuitive for me while working on long code. So I was kind of checking out other options. 
In future I will definitely keep your response in mind.

Comment: @Aconcagua C++ comes with lots of useless features just for the heck of inviting new useless features (and for the sake of adding even more poorly defined behavior and language bugs...). You can write `if(variable = value, variable == reference)` since the dawn of time in C and C++ both and it will work just fine. Just because you _can_ doesn't mean that you _should_.

Comment: @Aconcagua Or just `if(SomeStructWithDestructor::whatEver())` since that code doesn't make much sense anyway unless `whatEver()` is a static member. Otherwise there's also anonymous types `SomeStructWithDestructor().whatEver()`. Including the comma version and the brace version, that's 4 different possibilities that are all backwards compatible all the way to C++98 afaik. But... we _must_ create new useless C++ features for the heck of it...

Comment: @Aconcagua Because calling a member function of a default initialized struct just about to be destroyed again doesn't seem very meaningful unless that function could as well have been static - that is, it comes with side effects.

Comment: @Lundin The constructor might have done quite some useful stuff – we might have parameters passed to, or we might simply want to limit the scope of a variable similarly to what the for loop does, like `if(auto ptr = f(); ptr) { ptr->doSomething(); /* delete ptr ? */ }`. I stay with, it *can* be useful. However I just notice: It's the wrong place to discuss, it's a *C* question, so indeed I shouldn't ever have mentioned it here :( Agree on deleting all of here?